# didSelectRowAtIndexPath won't fire when moved offscreen

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UITableView` that is initially offscreen and when a button is pressed, I shift the center point of the view to the right, moving the tableview back on the screen.  Similar to the menu in Facebook.

```
//Slide in Side Menu
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];    
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.75];

self.view.center = CGPointMake((cgSize.width/2)+10, 165);

[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];    

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

My problem is that when the top left corner of my tableview is a negative number(off screen) the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will not fire and selection is disabled for some reason.

```
menuTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-350, 0, 350, cgSize.height-50) 
                                                 style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

When I change -350 to 0, it works perfectly, like this:

```
menuTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, cgSize.height-50) 
                                                 style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: when you are doing this menuTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-350, 0, 350, cgSize.height-50) 
                                                 style:UITableViewStylePlain]; , your entire frame should not be visible, how are pressing the table cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table view's frame is outside the view's standard frame, so the input is not being forwarded down to the table view.  You need to figure out how to keep the bounds of the table view contained within its parent view, while still animating the way you want it to

Comment: It works when I shift all of my view individually and then my UITableView.  Just using  self.view.center = CGPointMake((cgSize.width/2)+10, 165);  doesn't work.